# Add attributes to Insert Image dialogue of Umbraco RTE or Create Custom Data type

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

How can I add attributes to the current Insert Image dialogue box on umbraco Richtext Editor?

What I really want is to let content editor choose images and set their class, and maybe choose if this is lightbox image or not. If user choose lighbox option, then a hyper link  is added with some extra attributes, like data-rel. I even want to be able to modify the image url added by the content editor, if possible.

The output should look like this

```
<a href="/media/2813/DSC_2615.JPG" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gal-3-col]" >    
   <img src="http://domain.com/imageGen.ashx?
   image=%2fmedia%2f2813%2fDSC_2615.JPG&amp;width=420" alt="DSC_2615" title="DSC_2615" 
   class="alignright">
</a>
```

I found this very useful link http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst8163_TinyMCE--insert-image-dialog.aspx which solve half of my issue, but I can't figure out how to continue

Comment: Have you found out how to do this? I'd like to do the same! (on Umbraco 5 / Jupiter)

Comment: Not really :(... What I found is how to add a class name to anything the content editor may add into the richtexteditor (RTE) box using Style drop box provided by Umbraco. let me know if this is something you want me to explain how!

Answer (score 2):

Default umbraco tinymce add image interface is

```
<plugin loadOnFrontend="false">umbracoimg</plugin>
```

I was able to modify it to show additional field in the image selection interface, then render markup I want.

I edited \umbraco\plugins\tinymce3\insertImage.aspx, added my field there and some jquery logic:

```
<ui:PropertyPanel id="pp_desc" runat="server" Text="Description">
    <input type="text" id="title" style="width: 300px"/>
</ui:PropertyPanel>
...
```

Then if you are adding custom attributes, you might want to add them to \config\umbracoSettings.config

```
<!-- what attributes that are allowed in the editor on an img tag -->
<allowedAttributes>src,alt,title,border,class,style,align,id,name,onclick,usemap</allowedAttributes>
```

and \config\tinyMceConfig.config

```
<validElements>
<![CDATA[+a[id|style|rel|rev|charset|hreflang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur|onclick|
ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup],-strong/-b[class|style],-em/-i[class|style],
-strike[class|style],-u[class|style],#p[id|style|dir|class|align],-ol[class|reversed|start|style|type],-ul[class|style],-li[class|style],br[class],
img[id|dir|lang|longdesc|usemap|style|class|src|onmouseover|onmouseout|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|umbracoorgwidth|umbracoorgheight|onresize|onresizestart|onresizeend|rel],
-sub[style|class],-sup[style|class],-blockquote[dir|style|class],-table[border=0|cellspacing|cellpadding|width|height|class|align|summary|style|dir|id|lang|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],
-tr[id|lang|dir|class|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],tbody[id|class],
thead[id|class],tfoot[id|class],#td[id|lang|dir|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bgcolor|background|bordercolor|scope],
-th[id|lang|dir|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|scope],caption[id|lang|dir|class|style],-div[id|dir|class|align|style],
-span[class|align|style],-pre[class|align|style],address[class|align|style],-h1[id|dir|class|align],-h2[id|dir|class|align],
-h3[id|dir|class|align],-h4[id|dir|class|align],-h5[id|dir|class|align],-h6[id|style|dir|class|align],hr[class|style],
dd[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],dl[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],dt[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],object[class|id|width|height|codebase|*],
param[name|value|_value|class],embed[type|width|height|src|class|*],map[name|class],area[shape|coords|href|alt|target|class],bdo[class],button[class],iframe[*],code[*]]]>
  </validElements>
```

Then I modified the .js that is in charge of rendering html that will be added to tinymce editor:

```
\umbraco_client\tinymce3\plugins\umbracoimg\js\image.js

ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<div id="__dimps_width" class="img-with-text"><img id="__mce_tmp" /><p id="__dimps_desc">description</p></div>', { skip_undo: 1 });
ed.dom.setAttribs('__mce_tmp', args);
ed.dom.setAttrib('__mce_tmp', 'id', '');
ed.dom.setAttribs('__dimps_width', {style: 'width: ' + nl.width.value + 'px;'});
...
```

One important thing: everything is cached and bundled, so to make sure your changes was applied remove all files from \app_data\TEMP\ClientDependency\ and use new instance of incognito browser. You probably can disable it somewhere, but I just removed the cache.

There is no magic in Umbraco TinyMCE. Just a bunch of .aspx and .js code. Modify it to your needs.

Comment: how do you know the value of the attribute in terms of what it'll look like on the nl object? like what would alt. text be?