# Umbraco 4.7 - Adding Alt. tag settings to tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

The person who manages our site wants me to add an alt. text option to the insert image button.

I managed to figure out how to do that, but am lost on how to get tinymce to actually apply the text and add the alt attribute to the image html.

I found an SO article that somewhat helped but didn't helped me with the thing I'm stuck on.
[Add attributes to Insert Image dialogue of Umbraco RTE or Create Custom Data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081096/add-attributes-to-insert-image-dialogue-of-umbraco-rte-or-create-custom-data-typ?rq=1)

Comment: "I found an SO article that somewhat helped but didn't helped me" What article do you mean? Where is you code samples thats doesnt work?

Comment: updated post with SO Article I read. its not that it doesn't work it doesn't address my issue fully.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. You just want the insert image button in TinyMCE to show alt text, or you want it to be configurable somehow? I'm running a version of 4.7.1.1 that has alt text on the insert image button that says "Insert/edit image".

Comment: i want to be able to define the alt text from the custom textbox i added, which i created that field but it doesn't accept it. that's my problem

Comment: I can't find anything to helpful for altering the tag dynamically. First of all make sure you have alt listed in ValidElements in /config/tinyMCEConig.config for TinyMCE. Otherwise I don't see a way in TinyMCE, only methods I see describe having a property string for that image and modifying it using XSLT.

Comment: do you know how i can do that with xslt, i seen that too but have no clue how to do that.